# How do I fix Javadoc that no longer autofills/autocompletes?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, javadoc, workspace

When you type /** and Enter above a method in Eclipse, it will generate the Javadoc, for example:

```
/**
 * Finds a World using a String, greets the World,
 * and then returns a reference to the World.
 * 
 * @param world - the World to find and greet.
 * @return the reference to the World.
 * @throws ApocalypseException - if the World is not found.
 */
public World helloWorld(String world) throws ApocalypseException {
    ...
}
```

However, sometimes when I am adding Javadoc to methods, it will randomly stop generating:

```
/**
 * 
 */
public Universe helloUniverse(String universe) throws BigBangException {
    ...
}
```

This is not specific to a class. I will generate 5 or so methods in a class and then it simply stops generating. I assumed that Workspace could not read my class files, so I deleted them and recompiled, but this did not fix the issue. I've also tried restarting Eclipse and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I cut all the methods that were not generating Javadoc into a class with similar imports and then proceeded to generate the Javadoc comments in that other class and they generated correctly. I then cut them back into the original class without any errors.

This might be a bug in Eclipse, because it happens to me quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno your specifics, but if you try to create a method that it can't quite figure out (e.g., put a class you haven't imported yet as a return value), you'll get the second result in place of the desired one.

Either way, you can try to force the javadoc comment generation by highlighting the method name and using "Source"->"Generate Element Comment" (from context menu or window menu bar).  Or the hotkey for that, whatever it's assigned to in your eclipse prefs.

Comment: If I try to generate comments that way, it uses non-Javadoc comments:

`/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */`

Comment: Your first suggestion was accurate. Adding a new method with a new return value did result in correct Javadoc generation at the bottom of the class. However, applying the same logic and removing all imports from the class to force errors did not change how the Javadoc comments were generated.

Comment: the "non-Javadoc" comment you show is default behavior for a comment on an overridden method.  You can change this in Prefs->Java->Code Style->Code Templates, via Comments->Overriding methods item.

Comment: not sure i understand - you're removing all the imports and javadoc comments are being auto-generated?  if so, success.  if no, that's to be expected, as mentioned in answer.  kind of sounds to me you may need to be check for errors in your class, either via (default) overlay of red squiggly lines on stuff, or in your Markers view (once file is saved).

Comment: There were no errors or even warnings in my class. As I said in my question, it would simply not generate the Javadoc comments.